# ldap authentication fails when running tomcat server in eclipse. Permission denied

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, ldap

I have a project with ldap authentication, when I run tomcat server from *startup.bat*, authentication works fine. But if I start tomcat server in eclipse (for debugging), authentication always fails and there is no errors on server startup. In eclipse server is using tomcat installation 
When i'm trying to connect, i'm getting this exception

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: ghxdcvip-p.ghx.com:389; nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: ghxdcvip-p.ghx.com:389 [Root exception is java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling IPv6 in VPN connection solved this problem